# CSS Can't move my images

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to move some images but I can't move them. I moved other images just fine but these ones won't move?

**HTML**: (it's a little larger with more images but i can't even move one)

```
<main> 
  <p class="window1"> Window 1 </p>
  <img class="uparrow1" src="images/up.png" alt="Up">
</main>
```

**CSS:**

```
.uparrow1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

It doesn't response at any command.

Comment: is main set to position: relative?

Comment: there is a typo mistake in css : `left:100px`

Comment: @MinalChauhan top should still work though?

Comment: @ Minal Oh yeah, that's just in the post not in my code, thanks.

Comment: @ ovokuro no it's not, let me try. 
edit: This was the fix, thanks.

Comment: @MikeHunt you're welcome

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g17mwLgt/ - your code seems to work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to set the containing div to `position: relative`, in this case `.main`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't move your child elements positioned in absolute if you don't set your parent element in relative.

Ex.

CSS

```
.parent{
  position:relative;
}

.child{
  position:absolute;
  left:100px;
}
```

HTML code

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Move me</div>
</div>
```

Resources for more info: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp